# Is there some way to extract ram files from Linux kernel dump

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I know that this is a very vague question, was not able to find any answer any where else that's why post the question here. It would be really helpful. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: What is "ram file"? And what dump do you mean, kdump?

Comment: Files those are in ramfs and yes kdump

Comment: Theoretically you can, but i doubt that something close to that is implemented in crash utility, so probably you will need to support this by yourself

Comment: You might get more informed help over on the [unix.se] site.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do what you're asking in crash.  You'll have to find those files/pages specifically and read them from memory.

The kmem command might be able to help you find the address of pages you're looking for. `help kmem` will get you all the options you can pass to it.

If by ramfs, you mean files from tmpfs, you can use the `mount` command to show mounted filesystems, so...

crash> mount
    VFSMOUNT         SUPERBLK     TYPE   DEVNAME   DIRNAME
    ffff88204ac70a80 ffff88204b2fb400 tmpfs  tmpfs     /dev/shm

crash> struct vfsmount ffff88204ac70a80
  mnt_root = 0xffff88204fdbd2c0,

From there, with a lot of work, you should be able to traverse the directory tree and, I believe, find the addresses those files are stored in memory.  From there, you can use the `rd` command to read the pages (see `help rd`).

Good luck!